# Prevent people from sending multiple forms without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've currently got a working PHP/AJAX form. It shows a form-message when the form is sent, or when it has an error. But, the page doesn't refresh when the form is sent, so it'll be easy to send multiple emails by just a simple double click (or even more clicks). Have a look at my code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                        <ul class="form-style-1">
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" class="field-divided" maxlength="15"  placeholder="Voornaam *" />&nbsp;<input type="text" id="mail-lastname" name="lastname" class="field-divided" maxlength="15" placeholder="Achternaam" >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" id="mail-email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *" class="field-long" maxlength="40" >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type ="text" id="mail-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" class="field-long" maxlength = "15">
                            </li>
                            <button class="mail-submit" id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Versturen</button>
                            <span style="color: #0184b2; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; margin: 0 auto; display: block; padding-top: 10px;" class="form-message"></span>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
```

**JS**

```
            $("form").on("submit",function(event){ 
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $("#mail-name").val();
                var lastname = $("#mail-lastname").val();
                var email = $("#mail-email").val();
                var phone = $("#mail-phone").val();
                var subject = $("#mail-subject").val();
                var information = $("#mail-information").val();
                $.post("donation-contact.php",
                    {
                    name: name,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    email: email,
                    phone: phone,
                    submit: "yes"
                    },
                    function(data){
                        $(".form-message").html( data );
                    }
                );
                });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $email_to = "#";

    $email_subject = "#";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];


    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;

    if (empty($name)) {
      echo "<span class='form-error'>Voer de verplichte velden in!</span>";
      $errorEmpty = true;
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo "<span class='form-error'>Geef een geldig E-mail!</span>";
      $errorEmail = true;
    }
    else {
      $formcontent=" Naam: $name \n\n Achternaam: $lastname \n\n Email: $email \n\n Telefoon: $phone";
      $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
      $headers = "From: ". htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) ." <" . $_POST['email'] . ">\r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
      mail($email_to, $email_subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
      echo "<span class='form-success'>De mail is verzonden!</span>";
    }

  }


?>
```

I've tried disabling the form button when it's being pressed. This works if the user doesn't make any mistakes, but it will also disable the button when it shows an error message.

Is there a way to disable the button only when the form is sent? Or to remove all the form input when the form is sent?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Disable the button when the form is sent, re-enable once you get a response (and clear the form fields if it is successful)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is basically already present in your code.

You intercept the submission via

```
$("form").on("submit",function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault();
     // ...
```

This is the place to disable the submit button:

```
$("form").on("submit",function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#mail-submit').prop('disabled', true);

    // ...
});
```

But you need a different treatment in the PHP script so that you can handle errors. Basiacally you need to send back a [JSON object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which will have a simple text property indicating the status (error / success) and a text property for the message (which may contain HTML).

PHP

```
if (empty($name)) {
    $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => '<span class='form-error'>Voer de verplichte velden in!</span>');
    $errorEmpty = true;
}
elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => '<span class='form-error'>Geef een geldig E-mail!</span>');
    $errorEmail = true;
}
else {
    // send email...
    $response = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => '<span class='form-success'>De mail is verzonden!</span>');
}

// No matter what happened, send the respons as a JSON object for easy treatment in JavaScript
echo json_encode($response);
```

Now in JavaScript you will receive an object, instead of text in you callback function:

```
function(data) {
    $(".form-message").html( data.message );

    // If there was an error you must re-enable the submit button 
    if (data.status === 'error') {
        $('#mail-submit').prop('disabled', false);
    } 

}
```

Comment: For some reason this wracks my form. I'm sure that your code should work, since it is so well explained. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What exactly happens and where? In the JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: It doesn't show an error or succes message, the form is not being received anymore, and the button gets disabled after clicking it (with or without content)